# Help me understand a stag joke in a movie

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, cinema

In the movie "Bachelor Mother" (1939), the hero, a wealthy socialite and the son of a big store owner, invites the heroine, a poor girl working at that store, to a New Year's party because the girl he tried to go with stood him up, and is also attending. He presents the heroine as Swedish and not understanding any English, and she plays along; so when they're leaving and he asks the original date what she thought of the heroine, the girl replies, with poorly disguised jealousy (around 53 minutes into the movie):

> "She's not bad for a fill-in. Personally, I'd just as soon go stag."

Then the heroine says the following line, revealing thereby that she speaks English and understood what was just said:

> "You could, too, with those shoulders."

This is treated by the hero as a terrifically funny joke. He can't stop laughing.

My question is: what's the joke? I understand that "to go stag" means "to go alone". I understand that the girl was saying "I'd just as soon go stag" rhetorically putting herself in the hero's place, while the heroine sarcastically pretends to understand the words to apply to herself. But what's the relevance of the (maybe overly bared?) shoulders? Is it "your broad shoulders make you a likely candidate for going stag, because you're ugly and no one will want you for a date"? Is it "with those shoulders you physically resemble a stag, the animal"? Is it something else?

Comment: I understand "to go stag" to apply to a man rather than to go alone in a gender-neutral  context. For example a "stag party" or a "stag do" (in a British context) is a party of men one of whom is about to get married, the equivalent for women is a "hen party". The joke is a little obscure to me but I read it as meaning either that the original date's shoulders are so wide that she could pass for a man or that she could pass for a male deer.

Comment: Thank you, that does seem very likely to me to be the right explanation!

Comment: I've never seen this exact usage before, but to my mind the context (plus basic knowledge of how "stag" is used in English) makes it blindingly obvious that ***to go stag*** means (for a man) to attend a social even without being accompanied by a partner of the opposite sex.

Comment: It's a simple pun, exactly as you propose. The original date is using an idiomatic expression about attending a social event alone, but the heroine chooses the literal meaning (i.e. "with those shoulders you physically resemble a stag, the animal") as a caustic rebuttal. This joke would be obvious to most native English speakers, so your question might have been more suited to our other site, [ell.se]. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is somewhat speculation, but the word "stag" refers specifically to a male deer.  "Going stag" originally referred just to men attending a party without a date, but is now used regarding women. Men tend to have wider shoulders then women, so the heroine is saying that she has broad enough shoulders to pass for a man.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense! I completely missed the male angle in "going stag", and it seems very likely that's what the remark about the shoulders was referring to.